# How can I check my CPI calculation is correct?

Tags: clock, calculation, processor

I got a CPI of 20.15 on the exercise below, but this value seems too high to me. How can I check if this is correct?

> A processor with 7.5 GHz clock frequency runs a program with 8000 millions instructions (8*10^9) in 21.5 seconds.
>
> What's the average CPI assuming that the program above is a representation of the average kinds of programs that runs in this computer?

I've tried it in many different way but I keep getting a CPI of 20.15. Is this correct?

Comment: Please elaborate your question.

Answer (score 0):

Instructions per second = (8000 ÷ 21.5) million
Clock frequency = 7.5 GHz

So, CPI = (7.5 × 1000) ÷ (8000 ÷ 21.5) = 20.15.

So, yes 20.15 is correct.

Comment: Lovely, Thanks GKB!